# Android Gradle execute task dependencies on Android build/run/debug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have one Android library module. I have included two tasks into it's .gradle as follows :

```
task createSDK(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn assemble

    def jarFile = file('build/intermediates/bundles/release/classes.jar')
    def outputDir = file("build/libs")
    archiveName = "mylib.jar"
    destinationDir = outputDir
    from {
        configurations.compile.filter({ (it.name =~ /androidannotations-api.*\.jar/) }).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    } {
        exclude "META-INF/**/*.*"
    }

    from {
        zipTree(jarFile)
    } 
}

// Copy "mylib.jar" file from the Library module to app module.
task copySDKJar(type: Copy)

copySDKJar {
    from('./build/libs')
    into('../app/libs')
    include('*.jar')
}

copySDKJar.dependsOn createSDK
```

I want to execute "copySDKJar" task automatically when user selects build/run/debug from Android Studio IDE. "copySDKJar" task depends on "createSDK" so it will executes "createSDK" task when we execute "copySDKJar". I tried some combination with "dependsOn", "mustRunAfter" but unfortunately it is not working. I am new to gradle, please help me.

---

***NOTE :*** Do not suggest to add module dependency.